# Resampled data going below 0 - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

When resampling a large dataset down 100x - some of the data-points end up negative despite no negative numbers present in the original dataset. Is this an unavoidable consequence of the resampling process or is there a better method to accomplish this?

I'm using:

```
a = resample(data,round((length(data))/1000),length(data));
```

Original dataset:

[image]

Resampled dataset:

[image]

I know that I can just filter out all values <0 but I want to understand why this is happening and if there is a better way to resample as this may be skewing my results.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I've attempted to use interp1 to scale my data down however it has not provided the expected result so I am either using the function incorrectly or it is not the right one to use for my problem.

The above input scaled down to:

[image]

Using:

```
x= [1:1:230208]; %length of the imported data (hitcount)
y = hitcount'; %hitcount is my imported data shown above
z = [1:1:2300]; %I want to scale it down roughly 1000x
a = interp1(x,y,z);
```

**EDIT 2**:

Just discovered that if I smooth my input by the same factor that i'm going to resample by (using a Hann window and `conv`) that when I resample I get a much more accurate output + very minimal negative values.

Comment: `resample` applies an anti-aliasing filter, whose impulse response will have some oscillations (similar to a `sinc` function). Hence the negative values

Comment: In your last `interp1` call, z should be the indices of the decimated signal. E.g., if you want to decimate by 2, use `z = 1:2:230280`. You can also use non-integral indices and `interp1` will use linear interpolation to produce the values at fractional indices.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now. Unfortunately it destroys quite a lot of the data (mostly relative peak heights) so resample may be better after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let`s take this simple example:

```
resample([1,0,0,1],8,4)
ans =
```

Columns 1 through 5

```
1.0000    0.7436    0.0000   -0.4035    0.0000
```

Columns 6 through 8

```
0.7436    1.0000    0.5644
```

You can see that the line is continued in some kind of curve. If you would expect the method to fill the gap between two `0` with another `0` you have chosen the wrong function, take a look at `interp1`

Short example to use `interp1`:

```
%some "high resolution" sin wave
x=[0:.1:10]
Y=sin(x)
%get 5 sample points
interp1(x,Y,[0:pi/2:2*pi])
```

Comment: How could interpl be used to scale data down? I was under the impression it could only increase the size by filling in gaps.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I fully understand the syntax of interp1 - what is the third argument specifying ([0:pi/2:2*pi])?

Comment: That's what I originally thought but given that [0:pi/2:2*pi] = 0, 1.57, 3.14, 4.71, 6.28 - I do not really understand why replacing [0:pi/2:2*pi] with [0:1:6] makes such a stark difference to the outcome (unless using pi is for mathematical reasons).

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of `resample` using band-limited (aka "sinc") interpolation.

The samples are assumed to have been generated by a band limited signal. `resample` filters the signal using a 'sinc' function (~sin(x)/x), and then decimates the result.

If you know the signal is non-negative, you might want to replace the sinc filter with a function that is non-negative. For example, in image processing, resampling is performed using Gaussian filters since pixel intensities are non-negative.

The `resample` function accepts an argument specifying the filter to use:

```
y = resample(x, upsample_ratio, downsample_ratio, fir_filter)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of this. I will have to look into fir filters a bit more to see if they are of use to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got no negative data in your initial dataset, perhaps your could consider taking `data_log = log(data)`, then resample `data_log`, and then take `exp(data_log_resampled)` to retrieve your resampled initial data.